# How to keep switch setting in dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

It's my problem.
[image]

This's my code:

```
dialog = new Dialog(FragmentOne.super.getActivity(),R.style.selectorDialog);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mod);
       Switch switch1 = (Switch) dialog.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                try {
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                                try {
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
dialog.show();
```

Switch2 and Switch3 are same code as Switch1,so I pass this part.
When I open again, it's reseted again.
Any one know how to solve this?

Comment: You have to save the state of `Switch` somewhere like `sharedPreferences`. And then get the value from preference and update the state with respect to the value.

Comment: use switch1.setChecked(true);

Comment: check answer for your problem

Answer (score 1):

while switching your control try to keep your values in your preferences like this

```
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        storeValue("switch1",isChecked);

    }
});
private void storeValue(String key,Boolean status) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, status);
        editor.commit();

}  
private boolean getValue(String key) {
        SharedPreferences myPrefs;
        myPrefs= getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return myPrefs.getBoolean(key,false);
 }
```

in your dialogue on create method

```
public class yourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            //do your logic here like switch on etc
     switch1.setChecked(getValue("switch1"));
       // switch2.setChecked(getValue("switch2")); so on..
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your solution!

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to save switch status values in shared preferences.
2. Then retrieve these values whenever creation of dialog like before setContentView().
3. Then set switch status accordingly by switch.setChecked() method.

For saving value in shared preferences:

```
 if (switch1.isChecked()) 
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.abc", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("switch1", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.abc", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("switch1", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

For Retrieve values from shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.abc", MODE_PRIVATE);
    toggle.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("switch1", true));
```